# Is it possible to execute a sql statement containing variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to execute a sql statement containing variable?

```
    DECLARE @SCHEMA varchar(40)

    set @SCHEMA='X_SLF'

   select * from @SCHEMA..Acc_tblCompany  --// anyway to use this type of statement?

   --below statement works 
    select * from X_SLF..Acc_tblCompany
```

--I don't want to do this following solution:

```
    DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(80)
    set @Sql=' select * from '+@SCHEMA+'..Acc_tblCompany'
    Execute sp_executesql @Sql
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. SQL is not very flexible when it comes to this

Comment: Since your varibale is declared as varchar(40), I don't think you'll be able to use it like this. The 2nd query seems better suited.

Comment: No, it is only possible to put a variable in the from clause, if it is being executed as dynamic SQL - that is the only way. So the "dont want" solution, is the ONLY feasible solution

Comment: You can't parameterize the objects in an SQL statement. Notice, in your first example, that what you're attempting to provide is a *string*, when what SQL Server wants in that position is a *name*. Although they may seem similar, they're really not.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could implement this as a case statement. It's not quite what you're asking for, but at least you can create the illusion to the caller that it's parameterized wrt schema